# real time sync device contacts with ionic application

Tags: swift, ionic3

Friends I need help in sync contacts from mobile to my ionic app just like when we save the new contact in our device, it automatically syncs to WhatsApp and other applications, I need the similar function to use in my application. Whenever user adds contacts to mobile, it should automatically sync to my ionic app.

I am looking for swift and fast reply,
thanks